# Creating Column with # Occurences of each pair of column values in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science

I'm trying to create a column with the number of occurences of each pair of column values in my dataframe (with more than 2 cols) of the following format.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAcUq.png): [image]

So far i've gotten the pair counts, but unsure how to exactly store this data in the form of a new column in my existing DF...also, the size of df and count is not same for some reason.
Appreciate any and all leads
Thank you!

```
df['Counter']=1
count=df.groupby(['Assigned To','Name']).agg('sum')['Counter'].to_frame()
df_sort=df.sort_values(['Assigned To','Name']).agg('sum').value_counts()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAcUq.png): [image: df and count with the different sizes...]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reset_index` method and also provide name like below

```
df_sort = df.sort_values(['Assigned To','Name'])
.agg('sum')
.value_counts()
.reset_index(name="Desired Column")
```

Comment: Still running been 15 mins lol, getting this in the terminal "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."

Comment: So you are getting error and it desnt work, which line is giving error?